# MBRs, VBRs, and partitioning of storage devices: how and why they vary across device-types?

Tags: audio, partitioning, mbr

The wikipedia entry for [Boot Sector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_sector) says this,

> - CD- ROMs usually have their own structure of boot sectors, for IBM PC compatible systems this is subject to El Torito specifications.

**Questions:**

1. So, do USB flash drives, DVDs, CD-RWs... too each have a structure of their own? And if not, why is a CD-ROM different from the rest, what is so special about it?
2. When it comes to creating multiple partitions on a storage device (one of which could be an extended-partition), do I need to worry about what storage device-type (CD, USB flash drive, HDD, DVD...) it is?
3. The wikipedia entry for [Volume](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_%28computing%29) has this to say

   > ... as floppy disks cannot be partitioned with most modern computer software.

Now, I have always thought that -- disregarding differences in their buses, form-factors, storage capacities, and other low-level hardware details -- all storage devices would be the same as far as their partitioning and bootability are concerned, so much so that I could simply copy enough initial sectors of a smaller device to a larger device regardless of the source and destination device-types (floppy, flash drive, CD, HDD, etc) and still have the larger device function *exactly* like the smaller device. But apparently not so, based on the above wikipedia entry.

I'd wonder why, though! I understand how wasteful it would be to have multiple partitions on a floppy drive, but why should it be anybody's business (the OS and other system software) to dictate such things?

4. The last of my questions on the same theme is: What device-types are mutually compatible to allow the copying of the device image of one to another, using a tool like `/bin/dd`? (Assuming, the destination device is as big as or bigger than the source device in terms of storage capacity.)